# Why is 0x41414141 associated with security exploits?

Tags: exploit

[This article](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/08/chromium-vulnerability-rewards-program.html) and [this search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=0x41414141&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) suggest that the 32-bit word `0x41414141` is associated to security exploits.

Why is `0x41414141` associated to security exploits?

Comment: Compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak.  My favorite is 0xDEADBEEF.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's nothing fundamental.  It's just a historical convention, like using `foo` as the name of a variable when you have no clue what to name it.

In more detail: The simplest way to test for a buffer overflow is to type a long string of A's (AAAAAAAA...) into a text field, and see what happens.  If the program crashes, it might be vulnerable.  If the program crashes and a debugger shows 0x41414141  in the program counter, ooh boy, you hit pay dirt: the program is almost surely vulnerable. (Remember, the ASCII code for 'A' is 0x41 in hex, so 0x41414141 is what you'd see if you looked at the byte-level representation of a string of A's in a hex editor.)

Why A's?  No reason at all; they're just the first letter in the alphabet.

So, this is a quick-and-dirty test that pentesters sometimes use.  But of course, there's nothing special about 0x41414141.  Douglas Adams fans could type in a long string of B's, and then look for 0x42424242.  That'd be equally effective, and even more fun.  I gotta remember to use that one in my next hacking demo.....

Comment: I always thought it came from Aleph One's seminal paper 'Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit' or at least was made popular by it.

Comment: Some researchers use A's due the the matter that it is easy to count. 41 -> 1 -> A, 42 -> 2 -> B etc etc.

Answer (score 6):

It's more associated with simple proof of concepts. 0x41414141 is usually the result when a (usually long) string of A's is used to demonstrate an overflow (or something similar).